# Sort based on the third column

Tags: files, sort

I'm facing a huge 4-columns file. I'd like to display the sorted file in stdout based on its 3rd column:

```
cat myFile | sort -u -k3
```

Is that enough to perform the trick?

Comment: Note that you can write this as `sort -u -k3 < myFile`.

Comment: As `sort -u -k3 myFile`, even

Answer (score 265, accepted):

```
sort -k 3,3 myFile
```

would display the file sorted by the 3<sup>rd</sup> column assuming the columns are separated by sequences of blanks (ASCII SPC and TAB characters in the POSIX/C locale), according to the sort order defined by the current locale.

Note that the leading blanks are *included* in the column (the default separator is the transition from a non-blank to a blank), that can make a difference in locales where spaces are not ignored for the purpose of comparison, use the `-b` option to ignore the leading blanks.

Note that it's completely independent from the shell (all the shells would parse that command line the same, shells generally don't have the `sort` command built in).

`-k 3` is to sort on the portion of the lines starting with the 3<sup>rd</sup> column (including the leading blanks). In the C locale, because the space and tab characters ranks before all the printable characters, that will generally give you the same result as `-k 3,3` (except for lines that have an identical third field),

`-u` is to retain only one of the lines if there are several that sort identically (that is where the sort key sorts the same (that's not necessarily the same as *being equal*)).

`cat` is the command to con**cat**enate. You don't need it here.

If the columns are separated by something else, you need the `-t` option to specify the separator.

Given example file `a`

```
$ cat a
a c c c
a b ca d
a b  c e
a b c d
```

With `-u -k 3`:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8

$ sort -u -k 3 a
a b ca d
a c c c
a b c d
a b  c e
```

Line 2 and 3 have the same third column, but here the sort key is from the third column to the end of line, so `-u` retains both. `␠ca␠d` sorts before `␠c␠c` because spaces are ignored in the first pass in my locale, `cad` sorts before `cc`.

```
$ sort -u -k 3,3 a
a b c d
a b  c e
a b ca d
```

Above only one is retained for those where the 3rd column is `␠c`. Note how the one with `␠␠c` (2 leading spaces) is retained.

```
$ sort -k 3 a
a b ca d
a c c c
a b c d
a b  c e
$ sort -k 3,3 a
a b c d
a c c c
a b  c e
a b ca d
```

See how the order of `a b c d` and `a c c c` are reversed. In the first case, because `␠c␠c` sorts before `␠c␠d`, in the second case because the sort key is the same (`␠c`), the last resort comparison that compares the lines in full puts `a b c d` before `a c c c`.

```
$ sort -b -k 3,3 a
a b c d
a b  c e
a c c c
a b ca d
```

Once we ignore the blanks, the sort key for the first 3 lines is the same (`c`), so they are sorted by the last resort comparison.

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort -k 3 a
a b  c e
a c c c
a b c d
a b ca d
$ LC_ALL=C sort -k 3,3 a
a b  c e
a b c d
a c c c
a b ca d
```

In the C locale, `␠␠c` sorts before `␠c` as there is only one pass there where characters (then single bytes) sort based on their code point value (where space has a lower code point than `c`).

Comment: I don't understand this answer. The linux manual *https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort* states: **-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]**
*:start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)*. Isn't this the reason why you need *-k 3,3* instead of simply *-k3*?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, yes and that's also what I'm saying here.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, Setting only POS1 means POS2 is "to the end of line"

Answer (score 31):

```
sort -t : -k 3 filename
```

when your delimiter is `:` and you need to sort the file `filename` by the 3<sup>rd</sup> field.

Comment: No, -k3 still sorts on the portion of the line that starts with the 3rd field (so after the second `:` with `-t :`) and ends at the end of the line, `sort -t: -k3,3` for the sorting key to be only the third field.

Answer (score 13):

```
sort -g -k column_number
```

is the right command to sort any list having numeric characters using specific column

Comment: Using -k was [covered pretty well already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104527/117549) so it would be helpful if you explained how this command is different or better. Maybe you could also include actual column numbers to address the OP's actual question.

Comment: This got me to use the man pages :p "-g, --general-numeric-sort, compare according to general numerical value" which was what I needed in my case.

Answer (score 5):

If you understand "column" as in text file (4th character) then yes, your solution should work (or even `sort -u -k3 myFile` to allow `sort` perform some memory-saving magics with random access). If you understand "column" as in database - a whole entity of data followed by a separator, and variable column width, you'll need something fancier e.g. this sorts ls -l by size

```
      ls -l |awk '{print $5 " " $0;}'| sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

(which is equivalent to trivial `ls -lS` but serves the example nicely.)

Comment: No, by default sort _columns_ are blank separated, they are not character columns, to sort on the 3rd character column, the syntax would be: `sort -k 1.3,1.3`. `ls -l | sort -k5,5n` to sort on the size.

Comment: The `awk` solution is exactly what I needed-- easily modified to fit complex sorting requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-n` flag if you want to sort numerically. Suppose the column you want to sort on is numeric

```shellsession
$ cat | sort -k 2 -n
zat 37 
sat  9
pat 13
gat 04
^D
gat 04
sat  9
pat 13
zat 37
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the awk [Velour library](//github.com/svnpenn/velour):

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/velour -f
{
  q[NR] = $3
  z[NR] = $0
}
END {
  a_sort_by(q, z)
  io_puts(q)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sort -k 1.3,1.3 myfile
```

Will sort your myfile file on the third column if your file don't have any separator.

```
$ cat myfile 
ax5aa 
aa3ya 
fg7ds 
pp0dd 
aa1bb

$ sort -k 1.3,1.3 myfile 
pp0dd 
aa1bb
aa3ya 
ax5aa 
fg7ds
```

man page of sort:

*[...]
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)
[...]
POS is F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the character position in the field; both are origin 1. If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from the beginning of the preceding whitespace. OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options, which override global ordering options for that key. If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.*

With --key=1.3,1.3, you said that there only one field (the entire line) and that you're comparing the third character position of this field.