# Unix sort by multiple columns

Tags: command-line, sort

I have trouble understanding unix sort. Consider the following file (tab separated)

```
aa  ~ a1
aa  B
b   A
b   ~ e
bb  B
bb  ~ B
```

When calling:

```
cat tmp2 | sort -t $'\t' -k1,2
```

I get

```
aa  ~ a1
aa  B
b   A
bb  B
bb  ~ B
b   ~ e
```

As far as I understand, -t $'\t' says to consider the separator to be a tab instead of a white space and -k1,2 says to sort by the first column and, if two rows have the same fist column, then by the second one. But in that case, shouldn't my last 'b' appear in the fourth row?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, `-k1,2` says to sort on the portion of the line that starts at the beginning of the first field and ends at the end of the second field.

To sort on the first field and then on the second, it's:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2
```

Comment: (edit I could not put each character to a different line in a comment)
So why then 'a~'

'a'

'a2'

'aa'

'aa3'
'aa~' will be sorted as 'cat tmp2 | sort -k1,1'
'a'
'a~'
'a2'
'aa'
'aa~'
'aa3' ? Since the '~' is after any other character in the ascii table, 'aa~' should be sorted after 'aa3' for example?

Comment: @giulio. The ASCII table is only relevant for sorting in the [C/POSIX locale](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763). String comparison in other locales is a lot more complicated and tries and work the same as in natural languages. For instance spaces are ignored in a first instance in most locales which is why "b c" sorts after "bb".

Comment: Are you sure there is a difference between `sort -k1,2` and `sort -k1,1 -k2,2`? At least from your description, I don't understand the difference between the two commands. `diff <(sort -t $'\t' -k1,2 <<<"$content") <(sort -t $'\t' -k1,2 -k2,2 <<<"$content")` and `diff <(LC_ALL=C sort -t $'\t' -k1,2 <<<"$content") <(LC_ALL=C sort -t $'\t' -k1,2 -k2,2 <<<"$content")` produced no output.

Comment: @Six, in the C locale, comparison is done byte-by-byte on the byte value, that is `strcoll()` (the comparison function used by `sort`) works the same as `strcmp()` there (and there only). So for `sort -k1,1 -k2,2` and `sort -k1,2` to produce different results, you need an input that contains characters that sort before the separator. In the case of TAB, that's going to be byte values 0 to 7 which are unlikely to be found in text, but you can compare on the output of `printf 'a\1\tb\na\tc\n'`.

Comment: @Six, see [that other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104527) for more detailed explanations.